# Span element in PHP function not reflecting with Styles

Tags: php, wordpress

Can please anyone assist to fix these two issues in PHP Code.

1. Span Inside DIV is not reflecting in Blue Color.
2. Italics text also reflecting inside DIV with *Bakground Color: #DCDCDC*. It should be outside of DIV.

   ```
   function send_admin_notification($post_id,$post_title) {
      $blogname = get_option('blogname');
      $email = get_option('admin_email'); 
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "From:".$blogname." "."
        < ".$email.">\n" . "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=\"" . get_option('blog_charset') . "\"\r\n";
       $message = __('A new post has been submitted in ','accesspress-anonymous-post').$blogname.'site.'.'
       <br/>
     <br/>'. '

   <div style="background-color:#DCDCDC;">
     <span style="font-color:Blue" New Post Submission </span>'.'
     <br/>
     <br/>'; 'Post Title: '.$post_title.'
     <br/>
     <br/>'; 'Post Module: '.$post_title.'
     <br/>
     <br/>
   </div>';

   $post_author_name = get_post_meta($post_id,'ap_author_name',true);
   $post_author_email = get_post_meta($post_id,'ap_author_email',true);
   $post_author_url = get_post_meta($post_id,'ap_author_url',true);

   if($post_author_name!=''){ 
     $message .= 'Post Author Name: '.$post_author_name.'
     <br/>
     <br/>'; 
   } 
   if($post_author_email!=''){ 
     $message .= 'Post Author Email: '.$post_author_email.'
     <br/>
     <br/>'; 
   } 
   if($post_author_url!=''){ 
     $message .= 'Post Author URL: '.$post_author_url.'
     <br/>
     <br/>'; 
   } 
   $message .= '
   <br/>
   <br/>'.__('

   <i>This is an auto generated email. For more details regarding this, please login to Wiki website','accesspress-anonymous-post.</i>');
   $subject = __('Process Wiki | New Post Submission','.$post_title.'); wp_mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
     }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

span hasn't been closed properly

```
<span style="font-color:Blue" New Post Submission </span>'
```

use the below one

```
 <span style="color:Blue"> New Post Submission </span>
```

Comment: Thank you. But Post Title and Italics text is not reflecting. Can you please check might be possible there is an error in opening/closing of span,div elements.

Comment: you should use the <em> instead if <i> as it is deprecated

Comment: @Web34 please accept the answer if you find it useful,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use inline style

```
<span style = "property:value;property:value;">Some text</span>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you. <span style="color:Blue;color:Blue;">some text </span> in my answer unfortunately it did't displayed.